# Adjust a numpy array based on the available ranges in another array

Tags: python, list, numpy, schedule

I have a numpy array (a) that represents the starting time of several activities. I also have another numpy array (b) of the times where the activities cannot operate. How to find array (c) which adjusts (a) based on (b) and its yearly multiplications (365*1)+b, (365*2)+ b , (365*3)+b ... (365*n)+b?

```
a = np.array([0,7,76,107,142,342,669,610,634,669,669,669,669,669,669,357,669,669,669,669,669,669,669,669,669,720,757,757,757,757,757,757,757,757,757,,757,757,757,757])

b= [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81,82,83,84,85,101,102,103,104,105,279,288,296,297,298,345,346,347,348,349,350]
```

For example, if we take the first activity in (a) which starts at 0, it should be adjusted based on (b) to start at 8 since the period 0-7 is unavailable. This will automatically shift the second activity that starts at 7 to start at 15 = (7 +8). The third activity which starts at 76 should start at 84 but 84 is a day where it cannot be operate. So it has to operate partially between 85 until 101 and the other part of this activity has to continue after 105 since 101 - 105 range is not available. The resulting array (c) should reflect this split by adjusting the start time of the fourth activity in array (a) that starts at 107.

So in concept, array (c) should have the same size as array (a) and the first four values should be:

```
c=[8,15,86,121,...
```

Thanks for your help.

Note: array(a) is not sorted and the order is important.

Comment: Are all activities 7 long?

Comment: Lets do that step by step. Try to find a working solution based on Python lists instead of Numpy arrays first. Once this works we can optimize the code to use Numpy.

Comment: Create the output list `c = []` and append solutions to it: `c.append(4)` Use Python's `in` operator to find if something is in a list combined with `if`.

Comment: You will also need the modulo operator for the values in `b` and the values > 365 in `a`.